# array child in php

Tags: php

i have this array
the name of array is $list

when i type this:

```
$mychild = $list[1]['children'];
```

but if there is no child i get this message

*A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: children
Filename: controllers/user.php
Line Number: 384*

how i can check if there is child in array items?

```
Array
    (    
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 7
                [children] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 9
                            )

                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 6
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 8
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [id] => 10
            )

    )
```

Comment: Something wrong with the PHP manual?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
isset($list[1]['children'])
```

or

```
array_key_exists('children', $list[1])
```

See [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset) and [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/array_key_exists)

Answer (score 2):

This way you will be sure that both `$list[1]` and `$list[1]['children'])` exist. So you will probably see no error(s).

```
if (isset($list[1]) && isset($list[1]['children']))
{
    // code here!
}
```

You may also check `if (isset($list))` to see if `$list` exists.

Answer (score 1):

Using `isset()` (which will return true if it exists), or using `empty()` which would return false if it isn't empty.

Comment: Be careful; "isn't empty" may not mean what you think it does.